# Post variable using pagination in bootstrap

Tags: php, post, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I need to post an additonal variable when using bootstrap. I have a dropdown menu that is working fine, but as a user selects from the dropdown menu I would also like to be able to choose a second input from a pagination list..

my code so far:

```
        <form action="racing.php" method="POST">
        <select name="meeting_codes" id="meeting_codes" class="span1" onchange="this.form.submit();">  
             <?php include('get_codes.php'); 
             $selected = $_POST['meeting_codes'];
                for($i=0; $i<count($data_array); $i++){
                echo' <option value="'.$data_array[$i][0].( $data_array[$i][0] == $selected ? '" selected="selected">' : '">' ).$data_array[$i][0].'</option>'; 
                }            
             ?>
        </select>  
    </form> 

    <div class="pagination">
        <ul>
        <?php
            for($j=1; $j<=12; $j++){
                echo '<li><a>'.$j.'</a></li>';
            }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I  include a PHP file that requires two $_POST variables, first from the drop down, and the second from the pagination list...

The first includes file (`get_codes.php`) creates an array for the dropdown menu.

How do I insert the second POST variable?

Answer (score 0):

i've managed a solution... whether it's appropriate or not, or elegant, i am unsure

old code:

```
echo '<li><a>'.$j.'</a></li>';
```

changed to:

```
echo '<li><a href="?meeting_code='.$selected.'&race_num='.$j.'">Race '.$j.'</a></li>';
```

where 'meeting_code' and 'race_num' are the variables need posted via $_GET